# How to update conteneditable div without changing cursor position

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

Here is the javascript code I am using and I want to highlighted the characters after 255 and should be shown in another div with diff color

```
$( "#testdiv" ).keyup(function() {
   if($("#testdiv").text().length>255)
   {
   var text = $("#info").text()
   $("#testdiv").text("")
   $("#testdiv").append(text.slice(0,255)+"<div>"+text.slice(255)+"</div>")
   }
});
```

Here is the HTML code,

```
<div id="testdiv"  contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

With this code the problem I am facing is

1. It is updating the cursor position to the beginning of text when I try to update text after 255 characters.
2. When there is less than 255 character inside div and I press enter then every time it appends a div enclosing the `<br>` tag.

Comment: try $("#testdiv").append(text.slice(0,255)+"<div>"+text.slice(255)+"</div>").focus();

Comment: for first point

Comment: @daulat: it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#testdiv").on('keyup', function() {
  if ($("#testdiv").text().length > 255) {
    var text = $("#testdiv").text()
    $("#testdiv").text("");
    $("#testdiv").html(text.slice(0, 255) + "<div style='color:red'>" + text.slice(255) + "</div>");

    var preHtml = $("#testdiv").html();
    $("#testdiv").html(preHtml);

    $("#testdiv").focus();
    placeCaretAtEnd(document.getElementById("testdiv"));

  }
});

function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
  el.focus();
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" &&
    typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    range.collapse(false);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    textRange.moveToElementText(el);
    textRange.collapse(false);
    textRange.select();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="testdiv" contenteditable="true">sample text
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Kapila Perera in you result as well the cursor is moving to the beginning

Comment: Kapila Perera : in updated code cursor moves at end instead of beginning. I want it to stay where I am inserting text.